# if selectors chaining?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

ok, im trying to animate something to different heights if a selected id has a selected class.
i have the following code.

```
 function myfunction() {


   if ($('#homebutton').hasClass("active"));
   {
    $('#content').animate({height: "240px",opacity: 1}, 100 , hideLoader());
   }

   if ($('#showbutton').hasClass("active"));
   {
   $('#content').animate({height: "79px",opacity: 1}, 200 , hideLoader());
   }

   if ($('#aboutbutton').hasClass("active"));
   {
   $('#content').animate({height: "527px",opacity: 1}, 300 , hideLoader());}

   if ($('#contactbutton').hasClass("active"));
   {
   $('#content').animate({height: "1040px",opacity: 1}, 400 , hideLoader());
   }
}
```

that is chaining the animations after each other no matter what i click it ends up being 1040px high what am i doing wrong??

tried changing it to

```
{if ($('#homebutton').hasClass("active"));
$('#content').animate({height: "240px",opacity: 1}, 100 , hideLoader());
}
```

with absolutely no effect

Comment: for 2 moments i thought you wanted to do chaining with if statements!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have separated the if statements from the code on the next line. The only thing that you execute when the condition is true is an empty statement.

Change this:

```
if ($('#homebutton').hasClass("active"));
```

into:

```
if ($('#homebutton').hasClass("active"))
```

and the same for the other three.

Comment: such a small change, huge difference! problem solvered, thanks mate.

Comment: Good catch. On a side-note, I find it funny that the **inclusion** of a semi-colon at the end of the line was the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You  can clean that up a lot by taking advantage of the nice language that Javascript is:

```
$.each({
  '#homebutton': { height: '240px', speed: 100 },
  '#showbutton': { height: '79px', speed: 200 },
  '#aboutbutton': { height: '527px', speed: 300 },
  '#contactbutton': { height: '1040px', speed: 400 }
}, function(selector, controls) {
  if ($(selector).hasClass('active'))
    $('#content').animate({height: controls.height, opacity: 1}, controls.speed, hideLoader());
});
```